# How to update record programmatically with ECK?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm playing with [Entity Construction Kit (ECK)](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) on a Drupal 7 site. In a custom module I need to add, update and get ECK record.

By admin panel I created my entity "company" and his bundle "company". In my module I already built add and get method for the entity record (methods are working).

But  how can I update a specific record ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about services or web enviroment?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment... but I'm in a custom module so it's the web environment of Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thousands of research, according to the page [Creating and Modifying Entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/1377614) this is the way to update an entity :

```
$entity = entity_load_single('entity_name', $entity_id);
$entity->title = 'new name';
$entity->save();
```

This will load the entity 'entity_name' with the id 'entity_id', then the title will be replace by 'new name'.

I hope its help.